# Create Calculated Value On Same Calculated Value Inside Previous Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a script to calculate "SHI" Column using SQL based on this table.

```
| Day | BR  | BR2 | HI  |  SHI   |
----------------------------------
|  1  | 0   |  0  | 0   |  0     |
|  2  | 400 | 400 | 95  |  95    |
|  3  | 0   | 400 | 0   |  95    |
|  4  | 350 | 750 | 100 |  97.33 |
|  5  | 350 |1100 | 100 |  98.18 |
```

I need to calculate the SHI Column using:

```
SHI  =  ((BR * HI) + (Prev.SHI * Prev.BR2)) / BR2
```

Just to be clear, the SHI Column do not exist in my data yet. That is what I am trying to have my query calculate. My problem is, I don't know how to get the previous SHI Value to insert on that formula for current day.

Any idea how to create this in SQL?

Comment: [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Not if the prior value of the `LAG` expression is required, @DaleK . That would require an rCTE or perhaps some windowed `SUMs`.

Comment: You will get division by zero error for the first row.

Comment: we can use case when more than 0 than calculated else 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cte you can achieve your desired result.

```
with cte as 
(
select day,br,br2,hi,(case when br2<>0 and br2 is not null then coalesce(round( ((br*hi))/br2,2),0) else 0 end)SHI from S66312677V2 where day=1
union all 
select s.day,s.br,s.br2,s.hi,
(case when s.br2<>0 and s.br2 is not null then coalesce(round( ((s.br*s.hi)+cte.shi*cte.br2)/s.br2,2),0) else 0 end)SHI from S66312677V2 s
inner join cte on s.day-1=cte.day
where s.day<>1
)
select * from cte
```

**Output:**

[image]

If number of rows is more than 100 then use **OPTION (MAXRECURSION xxx)** to set a larger recursion limit up-to 32,767 as below:

```
    with cte as 
        (
        select day,br,br2,hi,(case when br2<>0 and br2 is not null then coalesce(round( ((br*hi))/br2,2),0) else 0 end)SHI from S66312677V2 where day=1
        union all 
        select s.day,s.br,s.br2,s.hi,
        (case when s.br2<>0 and s.br2 is not null then coalesce(round( ((s.br*s.hi)+cte.shi*cte.br2)/s.br2,2),0) else 0 end)SHI from S66312677V2 s
        inner join cte on s.day-1=cte.day
        where s.day<>1
        )
        select * from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 999)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... but in this case is "the SHI Column do not exist in my data yet". So we need create a new column on that.

Comment: Ok. Let me allow some time.

Comment: is it possible to use with CTE ?

Comment: Tha's what I am thinking